# AWS Cognito refresh token Has been expired,any way to auto signin?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

When refresh token has been expired, required sign using hosted ui. is there any way to make auto sign when token expired?

Tried manually sign in using hosted UI, want to make auto sign in when ever refresh token expired.

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is: **No**.

As mentioned in the [document](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/amazon-cognito-user-pools-using-the-refresh-token.html):

> If the refresh token is expired, your app user must re-authenticate by signing in again to your user pool.

If you really need this, one possible way is to increase the validity period of the refresh token (Maximum value is 10 years). BUT please note that, in terms of security, having a long validity period for a refresh token is not a good practice. Hence, **not recommended**.